Calling a function that has the imported 'keyboard' parameter
I am working on a game in Python and haven't really used timers that often so I don't know much about them. I figured out I can import keyboard which tells me what key is pressed by the user. The problem with my little knowledge of timers is that I don't know how to call a function that has a keyword that I cannot pass when calling it with a timer. Please take in mind that I am in the dark when it comes to timers, so if my code looks weird that's why. I keep getting the ModuleNotFoundError: keyboard which I don't know how to deal with.
Im not including the entire code because this is the part that I'm asking about, but I can quickly add what the variables are.
dx is horizontal movement
dy is vertical movement
character is the player model
from browser import timer
import keyboard

def set_horizontal_movement(keyboard):
    if keyboard.read_key() == "ArrowRight" or keyboard.read_key() == "d":
        dx = 2
    elif keyboard.read_key() == "ArrowLeft" or keyboard.read_key() == "a":
        dx = -2
    character.move(dx, dy)
    dx = 0
timer.set_interval(set_horizontal_movement(), 1)

I have tried many different versions of timers and other fixes.

What is the type of timer object?

Just write def set_horizontal_movement(), and return dx at the end of the function

Seems like you're using Brython and writing everything to be run in-browser. This is not what people usually do when it comes to programming with Python, so keep in mind that much of what you'll find on the web may not to be applicable to your environment.
For example, I'm not sure if you can get the keyboard library to work there because it was written for regular Python installations.
You can find more info about how to interact with keyboard in Brython in the official docs:
from browser import bind, document

def keyevent(ev):
    # ev.type has event type like "keydown"
    # ev.key has event key that like "s"
    ev.stopPropagation()

document["key_keydown"].bind("keydown", keyevent)


Now about the timer. As Tom has mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't call the function with () at the end. More info about "functions that accept other functions as an argument" (i.e. higher-order functions) here. Python's map is exactly like that – find out why it should be map(str, [1, 2, 3]), not map(str(), [1, 2, 3]).
If you will need to pass a function to set_interval with some arguments embedded, you should do it with functools.partial instead, see here.
